# How to use #ifdef entities as part of functions in header files

Tags: c, header

I would like to ask if it is possible to use the entities defined in #ifdef block in header files. To be clear, I have following code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #include <winsock2.h>

    #define SOCKET_HANDLE     SOCKET
    #define CONNECTION_HANDLE SOCKET
#endif


SOCKET_HANDLE createServerSocket(const char* hostAddress, short port);
```

I am Java developer and this seems completely fine for me. However compiler has a problem with this.

Can you explain why is that code a problem?
Also how can I force to compile it. (The idea is to have generic interface and conditional compilation to determine real types according to running platform at compile time.)

Thanks

Comment: error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'createServerSocket', looks like it ignored the macro

Comment: Add `#pragma message(" WIN32 is defined ")` to inside the `#ifdef WIN32` branch. This should appear in the compiler output if `WIN32` is defined.

Comment: Is there any code prior to this block?

Comment: Nit-picking, but the port number needs to be `unsigned short`.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking - could you make this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#ifdef` is an conditional preprocessor statement. Much like `if` statements they need something to evaluate so one branch or another can be taken.

In the case of `#ifdef`, it is evaluating whether or not the given macro is defined. e.g.

```
#ifdef BLAH
/* true branch */
#else
/* false branch */
#endif
```

Checks to see if the BLAH macro is defined. Based on the result the code in either the true or false branch is included and compiled, the others discarded.

In your particular case, the usage of `#ifdef` is quite clearly to ensure the headers and socket types appropriate to operating system compiling the code is used (ignoring for the moment cross compiling).

For the code in your question, you want to check for the macro `_WIN32` and/or `_WIN64`. These are implicitly defined by most compilers targeting the Windows operating system. Note that in VC++ `_WIN32` is defined for 32bit and 64bit Windows, while `_WIN64` is only defined for 64bit Windows. See [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/2b24afa3-62ef-42d4-9aff-ca309588289c) for more details.

### Edit

Having noticed your changes to the question and the exact error message you posted in a comment, the problem is trifold:

1. `WIN32` is the wrong macro. It should be `_WIN32` or `_WIN64`. See above.
2. Because of 1, the `#define`s and `#include` is never seen by the compiler, and thus `SOCKET_HANDLE` and `CONNECTION_HANDLE` are both undefined.
3. Because of 2, when the compiler sees `SOCKET_HANDLE createServerSocket(const char* hostAddress, short port);` it doesn't recognise `SOCKET_HANDLE` and exits with an error

The solution is to fix the macro you are checking, changing it from `WIN32` to `_WIN32` or `_WIN64`. Further you should provide an `#else` branch in the event operating system detection completely fails, e.g. *assume* you are compiling on `$mostlikelyos` and `#define` and `#include` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. The weird part was that WIN32 worked from VisualStudio, but not from command line.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking excellent. Since this post solved the problem, can you kindly mark the answer as accepted? That's how stackoverflow works, and helps you and I both.

Answer (score 3):

There is missing token after the `#ifdef`. In this case it looks like you want to build for Windows:

```
#ifdef WIN32
```

You may need an `#else` branch when compiling on other platforms. For example:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #include <winsock2.h>

    #define SOCKET_HANDLE     SOCKET
    #define CONNECTION_HANDLE SOCKET
#else
    #define SOCKET_HANDLE     int
    #define CONNECTION_HANDLE int
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
```

SOMETHING is missing in your code

Read about pre-processing directives here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxhs2ty(v=vs.80).aspx

**EDIT** : After your edit to the question, I tried this out in Dev Cpp. It works fine as `WIN32` is defined for me. Even `_WIN32` is defined in my IDE. Both work well